# Why is my download status stuck at 19.7%?

Tags: download, bittorrent, utorrent

I do have an (albeit small) upload limit set, so my computer is seeding the torrent for other users, however my down limit is 200 and uTorrent is stuck at 19.7%.  The down speed is either blank, which I assume means that it is not downloading at all, or 0.0kb/s.  The up speed changes from 0.1kb/s to 0kb/s.  When I open the folder the video file is downloading to, there are multiple subfolders.  I opened one of these subfolders, inside is a short video file and some other files.

Comment: What "availability" does µTorrent report for that download?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like that torrent has poor sources.

When you download a torrent, you need to make sure that it has sufficient sources available. There are two kinds of sources that a torrent can have in its swarm:

- `Seeds - People who have the entire torrent (the whole file/all files)`
- `Peers - People who have none or some of the torrent`

In addition, different parts of the file(s) will usually be distributed in a way to maximize the availability, so that even if there are few or even no seeds, then the whole torrent could still be gotten if all of its pieces are available *somewhere* in the swarm.

Select the torrent then look at the following areas of the details pane and/or the torrent’s columns in the list. To get the whole thing, you need to make sure that either there is at least one seed or that the availability is greater than or equal to 1.0. Of course, the higher the number of seeds and availability, the better because there are more sources that you can download from, so it will complete faster.

[image: Screenshot of µTorrent with seeds, peers, and availability highlighted]